# Why is the switch-case statement not allowed upon Equality-Comparable classes?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, c++-concepts

Why is a C++ `class` satisfying the `EqualityComparable` **concept** NOT allowed to be used in a `switch`-`case` statement? What is the rationale behind this decision?

Here follows the `EqualityComparable` definition:

```
template <class T>
concept bool EqualityComparable() { 
    return requires(T a, T b) {
        {a == b} -> Boolean; // Boolean is the concept defining a type usable in boolean context
        {a != b} -> Boolean;
    };
}
```

Comment: Is the class constructor `constexpr`?

Comment: Consider adding `language-lawyer` tag

Comment: @Quentin - [Not quite](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#:label,case).

Comment: @StoryTeller that's what I get for trying to be pedantic without enough sleep :|

Comment: @Quentin - You weren't wrong. The class most be convertible to an integer, and be constexpr so the case labels could legal. I just pointed that there is a subtle bit of complexity involved.

Answer (score 3):

The `switch` statement was designed with [branch tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table) in mind. And so it requires that it operates with integer types <sup>1)</sup>. For me this is a historic reason, as I can easily see a relaxed rule where you can have any kind of comparable types, or even supply your own comparator.

Even as it is now, the compiler is not forced to use branch tables for `switch` (it is an implementation detail <sup>2)</sup>), so having a `switch` statement that cannot create these branch tables (with non-integer types) would not be an issue in my humble opinion.

---

<sup>1)</sup> or enumeration type, or of a class type contextually implicitly convertible to an integral or enumeration type

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

<sup>2)</sup> in fact the compiler can do all sorts of crazy things, e.g. generate a hibrid of classic conditional jumps with multi-level branch tables.

Comment: My class is indeed only a int wrapper, with type-safety and range-boundaries in mind (0 .. 9). While is ok to compare it to its underlying type, it would not be ok to be implicitly converted to its underlying type only to make it usable in a switch-case statement...

Comment: yes, I would not suggest adding implicit casts just for `switch`. In your case I could very easily live with `switch(static_cast<int>(my_ob))` or `switch(my_obj.to_int())` or `switch(my_obj.to_underlying())`, or even `switch((int) my_obj)`

Answer (score 1):

The switch-case statement can only be used for integral types, not arbitrary equality comparable types: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

The intention of creating the switch-case construct is that it creates a jump table instead of being just a line of if-then-else constructs, which is more efficient in most cases. It may not always be more efficient in modern CPUs with branch prediction, but the language was created way before branch prediction was a thing (and is not always used even now, for example embedded CPUs like ARM).

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 In my opinion (I haven't seen any official explanation) it's because C++ has to be fast even on the most constrained platform. So it has to keep the jump table behaviour with switch. (Keep in mind that it's only my opinion and not an official explanation)

Comment: @nefas I still think a compiler should be able to translate a fast jump table varsion of the code when the type is integral evaluable, and a slower version for the other cases... :/

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 True. I think there is a reason for not having a switch that use equality. (Personally I'm waiting for built-in pattern matching).

Comment: @nefas yeah, also. Those are like missing language features I do not find a good reason why, that is why I am asking if there is any official reason from the C++ Committee for not including.